# Computer gets frozen randomly

Tags: windows

I have a problem with my computer. It randomly freezes, at least once per day(no mouse/keyboard response).

I reinstalled windows7, changed the video card, checked the temperature and still got the problem.

I know that almost everything can cause this. I was Googling it and I found that a bad RAM is the most common reason.

Im going to test this now, but I want to ask you any other solution to this.

Comment: Besides RAM test your HDD too.

Comment: I would also check for faulty drivers. Do you also get BSODs or only hangups ?

Comment: Have you peeked at your event viewer? Under system events there are sometimes clues as to what may be going on.

Comment: Memory and HDD are the likely culprits, but I just ran into this issue the other day and I discovered it was a faulty mouse + keyboard. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Im going to try some disk tests and post here the results. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like there could potentially be a problem on the disk, maybe it is hanging trying to read a bad sector. I would suggest testing the Hard Drive to ensure it isn't failing.

There are a variety of bootable disk utilities to test the health of Hard Drives. One simple but effective tool to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.

If DFT reports that the drive is failing (diagnostics in red box) you should **IMMEDIATELY** back up anything of importance and then check to see if the drive is still under warranty to see if you can file an RMA on the drive.

If you haven't checked it out already, I recommend [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) for testing bad RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will do those tests ASAP. :)

Answer (score 0):

@jmreicha's answer pretty much covers what you need to know, but a very quick way to test your CPU and memory is to run 5-10 iterations of IntelBurnTest at maximum stress/memory usage -- it is also a very good system stability testing tool, more robust and useful than Prime95 in my opinion:

http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?197835-IntelBurnTest-The-new-stress-testing-program

If this fails, then there's definitely something wrong with either your CPU or RAM.